# sculpting - symmetry problem when adding clay on one side

Tags: sculpting

I wanted to add clay to one side and I expected it to mirror it on the other side based on the y symmetry setting. However, I did not expect it to remove material on the inside wall as shown attached. In fact it does not appear to add the mirrored clay very well on the other side.

I guess theres nothing I can do about this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you want to add material, use the draw brush, if you want the material to behave like clay, use the clay brush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because that side of your mesh is too thin and brush is too big, so basically you pull the front side, but backside is affected by too big brush as well... To change that go here and check this:

[image]

After checking Front Face Only, your brush will affect only vertices that are visible from your view... I am not sure though if this causes that bad symmetry, if symmetry still won't work, send me your file

Comment: @MikoCG....great thanks for this tip. I also selected 1 to make sure of normal view and it worked. NO deformation on the inside.